# Calculate statistical significance between binary and continuous data groups

Tags: statistical-significance

I would like to calculate statistical significance between two samples of sports data - one is `actual_wins` and the other is `expected_wins`. `actual_wins` is a binary data series (0 = loss, 1 = win) and `expected_wins` is a data series of continuous probabilities.

I have read about t-tests and chi-squared/McNemar (related groups) tests but this data violates the assumptions of both methods as the former assumes a normal distribution and continuous data while the latter assumes categorical/binary data.

Is there any method to calculate significance with this data?

Comment: Try searching this site for Brier score.

Comment: Yes, thank you @mdewey.